# Python file does not 'exist', yet is shown to

Tags: python, python-2.7

(Sorry if the question is misleading, i don't know how to phrase it well.)

while working with this code:

```
import os

#Lists files in the Import folder
for file in os.listdir("Imports"):
    if file.endswith(".wav" or ".mp3"or ".txt"):
        print file

#imports file into the editor
selected_file = raw_input("Which do you wish to modify?")

if selected_file in ("Imports"):
    new_file = selected_file
    print new_file
else:
    print("File does not exist or not available. please select another.")


It outputs:
boom.wav
Which do you wish to modify?
```

Which shows that the file exists and that 'boom.wav' is being seen by the code.  however, upon calling it in  "#Section with Trouble" (i.e. typing in boom.wav), i get the output:

```
Which do you wish to modify?boom.wav
File does not exist or not available. please select another.
```

Which means its raising the 'else' statement.

Why is it that i can't access the 'boom.wav'?

Comment: `("Imports")` is just a string. Starts with `"I"`, ends with `"s"`, etc. It's not a folder or a list of files or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if selected_file in ("Imports")`

to

`if selected_file in os.listdir("Imports")`

`("Imports")` is just a string, which is not what you want.

Comment: js, if your original answer was wrong and then you edit it to be pretty much the same as another answer (ie... mine lol) then its probs better to just delete the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if selected_file in ("Imports"):
```

is checking if `'boom.wav'` is in the string `"Imports"` (obviously not). This means that things like `'port'` or `'mpo'` would match.

Use:

```
if selected_file in os.listdir('Imports'):
```

Comment: Not a tuple - those are just grouping parentheses. `("Imports",)` with a comma would make a tuple.

Comment: I was just about to make that edit, but thank you @user2357112

Comment: Thank you this works! Quick note, it worked with 'listdir', not listdor'. Can't tell if that was a typo but thank you!